# Passing parametres to javascript functions via an event trigger / button click

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which is designed to add and remove additional input field to a div.

In a specific case, I could specify the div to which I would like the fields to be added when the function is called.

However, I want to have multiple buttons associated with multiple corresponding divs on one page which could call the function to add a field to *that* div.

The function:

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#DIV');
        var i = $('#DIV p').size() + 1;

        $('.addField').on('click', function() {
                $('<p><input type="text" id="field_' + i +'" size="20" name="field_' + i +'" value="" /> <a href="#" id="remField">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('.remField').on('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

As you can see the add field button listens for a button with the class "addField" to be clicked.

I would like that click to pass the parameter for #DIV to be equal to the # of the parent div of that button, is that possible?

EDIT: Per request here is my markup (example of) with function (note ??? placeholders)
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HnhC7/2/)

Comment: FYI `live` method is deprecated. You should use `on` instead.

Comment: Post your HTML markup and yes, it's possible

Comment: Not only is it possible, this is almost the exact question I use to phone screen candidates when I ask them to explain event delegation.

Comment: @tymeJV have edited post to include link to js fiddle with my markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/r9Cuh/) do the trick?

Html:

```
<div id="div">
    <div>
        <button type="button">
            <span>Add Field</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button">
            <span>Add Field</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button">
            <span>Add Field</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var i;
    i = 0;
    function fieldMaker () {
        i += 1;
        return $('<p><input type="text" id="field_' + i +'" size="20" name="field_' + i +'" value="" /> <a href="#">Remove</a></p>');
    }
    $(function () {
        $('#div').on({
            click : function () {
                $(this).closest('div').append(fieldMaker());
            }
        }, 'button');
        $('#div').on({
            click : function () {
                $(this).closest('p').remove();
            }
        }, 'a');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the information – where to add the input – at the button, for example using the HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<p><button data-add-field-to=".fieldset-1">add field to .fieldset-1</button></p>
<fieldset class="fieldset-1"></fieldset>
```

JS:

```
jQuery( function() {
    var i = 1; // your counter logic here
    jQuery( '[data-add-field-to]').each( function() {
        var $button = $( this );
        $button.on( 'click', function( event ) {
            var newFieldId = 'field_' + i,
                target = jQuery( $button.attr( 'data-add-field-to' ) );
            jQuery( '<input type="text" id="' + newFieldId +'" size="20" name="' + newFieldId +'" value="" />').appendTo( target );
            i++;
            return false;
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I'm just getting used to HTML 5, but am I right in my understanding that this wouldn't work in a browser that doesn't support it?

Comment: As you are using jQuery, which supported the data-attributes long before they where introduced in any browser: yes, that should work anywhere. You are not relying on some fancy browser capabilities here.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have a mapping between the buttons (let's say button id) and the elements to add to:

```
var mapping = {
  '#button1' : $('#receiver1'),
  '#button2' : $('#receiver2'),
  '#button3' : $('#receiver3')
}
```

One solution is to check which button the click event was triggered on:

```
$('.addField').on('click', function() {
  $('<mycontent>').appendTo(mapping(this.id));
  i++;
  return false;
});
```

A more elegant solution is to create a function for each button:

```
Object.keys(mapping).forEach(function(key){
  $(key).on('click', function() {
      $('<mycontent>').appendTo(this);
      i++;
      return false;
  }.bind(mapping[key])); // force this to be the receiver
});
```